How can I change a calculated 0(0%) to NA in tbl_summary Table
I am making a demographics table for a research project using tbl_summary. One of the variabels described is only applicable for the Cases and not the Controls, but I want it listed in the table anyways. The Controls all have a 'No' Value for Antibodies, whereas Cases can have either Yes or No. The issue I am running into is that I want to replace the '0' in the Control/Yes box with an NA. Is there a way to grab this specific location in the tbl_summary table?
tbl_summary(
  data,
  by = group, missing='no',
  type = all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical",
  statistic = list(
    all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)",
    all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ),
    include = c('age', 'sex', 'n_observations','antibodies'),
) %>%
  add_p(pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2), include=-antibodies) %>%
  modify_header(p.value = ("**P Value**"))%>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1** (N = {N})")




Characteristic
Overall
Cases(N=85)
Controls(N=85)
P Value




Sex






Female
77(45%)
43(52%)
34(40%)
0.17


Male
93(55%)
42(49%)
52(60%)



Antibodies Detected






No
140 (82%)
55 (65%)
85 (100%)



Yes
30 (18%)
30 (35%)
0 (0%)




I would like the Controls/Yes box replaced with an NA.
I would also like to remove the overall column from the antibodies as well. But this is only a subsection of the larger table, and I cannot figure out how to do that without removing it entirely.

Save the result of tbl_summary to an R object and then modify the cells of the $table_body attribute. Since you didn't provide any data, I will give an example using the survey dataset from the MASS package.
library(MASS)
data(survey)
head(survey)

A <- survey |> tbl_summary(
  by = Sex, missing='no',
  type = all_dichotomous() ~ "categorical",
  statistic = list(
    all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)",
    all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ),
  include = 'Fold') %>%
  add_p(pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)) %>%
  modify_header(p.value = ("**P Value**"))%>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1** (N = {N})"); A


A has attributes
attributes(A)
$names
[1] "table_body"    "table_styling" "meta_data"     "inputs"        "N"
[6] "call_list"     "by"            "df_by"

$class
[1] "tbl_summary" "gtsummary"

$table_body contains the data.
A$table_body
# A tibble: 4 × 13

  variable test_name           var_type var_label row_type label stat_0 stat_1 stat_2
  <chr>    <chr>               <chr>    <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Fold     chisq.test.no.corr… categor… Fold      label    Fold  NA     NA     NA    
2 Fold     chisq.test.no.corr… categor… Fold      level    L on… 98 (4… 48 (4… 50 (4…
3 Fold     chisq.test.no.corr… categor… Fold      level    Neit… 18 (7… 6 (5.… 12 (1…
4 Fold     chisq.test.no.corr… categor… Fold      level    R on… 120 (… 64 (5… 56 (4…
# ℹ 4 more variables: test_result <list>, statistic <dbl>, parameter <int>,
#   p.value <dbl>

Replace the middle cell "Neither:Female [6 (5.1%)]" with "NA":
A$table_body <- mutate(A$table_body, stat_1=ifelse(variable=="Fold" & label=="Neither", "NA", stat_1))
A


Edit:
And a better way to modify the table_body is to use the modify_table_body() function as suggested by Daniel Sjoberg in the comments.
A |> modify_table_body(
  ~.x |> dplyr::mutate(
    stat_1=ifelse(variable=="Fold" & label=="Neither", "NA", stat_1))
  )

The same method can be used for your second question.
detach(package:MASS)


This is a great solution. I would add that you can modify the .$table_body object with modify_table_body() and there will be checks to ensure internal compatibility has been maintained.
